Why am I getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException in Entity Framework Core when no other requests are being made?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API that uses Entity Framework Core to manage exam attempts and answers. In my Update method, I fetch an ExamAttempt, modify some related answers, and then save the changes using UnitOfWork.Save(). However, I keep encountering a DbUpdateConcurrencyException with the message:

The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I'm the only one testing this endpoint, so there shouldn't be any concurrent requests or changes to the data.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
public async Task<OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>> Update(Guid id, UpdateExamAttemptDto attemptDto, Guid studentId)
{
    var includeProperties = "ExamAttemptAnswers,Exam";
    var ExamAttempt = await UnitOfWork.ExamAttempt.Get(a => a.Id == id, includeProperties);

    if (ExamAttempt == null) 
    {
        return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Failure("Exam attempt not found");
    }

    // getting all exam questions
    var examQuestions = await UnitOfWork.ExamQuestion
                                        .GetAll("Question, Question.QuestionChoices", q => q.ExamId == ExamAttempt.ExamId);

    // calculating exam end date
    var ExamEndDate = ExamAttempt.Exam.StartAt.AddMinutes(ExamAttempt.Exam.DurationInMinutes);

    var canModify = ((ExamAttempt.StudentId == studentId) && 
                     (ExamEndDate >= DateTime.Now) && 
                     ExamAttempt.SubmittedAt == null);

    if (!canModify) 
    {
        return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Failure("You no longer can modify this attempt");
    }

    var answersToAdd = new List<ExamAttemptAnswer>();

    foreach (var updatedAnswer in attemptDto.answers)
    {
        var associatedQuestion = examQuestions.ToList().Find(q => q.QuestionId == updatedAnswer.QuestionId);

        if (associatedQuestion == null) 
        {
            return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Failure("The question you're trying to access is not found in this exam");
        }

        var questionHasAnswers = ExamAttempt.ExamAttemptAnswers.Any(a => a.QuestionId == associatedQuestion.Id);

        if (questionHasAnswers && associatedQuestion.Question is MultiChoiceQuestion) 
        {
            return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Failure("You can't add more answers to MCQ");
        }

        var questionChoiceBelongsToQuestion = associatedQuestion.Question.QuestionChoices
            .Any(c => c.Id == updatedAnswer.AnswerId);

        if (!questionChoiceBelongsToQuestion)
        {
            return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Failure("The answer you're trying to select doesn't belong to the question");
        }

        var answerAlreadyExists = ExamAttempt.ExamAttemptAnswers
            .Any(a => a.QuestionId == associatedQuestion.Id && a.AnswerId == updatedAnswer.AnswerId);

        if (answerAlreadyExists) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        answersToAdd.Add(new ExamAttemptAnswer() {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ExamAttemptId = ExamAttempt.Id,
            AnswerId = updatedAnswer.AnswerId,
            LastModified = DateTime.Now,
            QuestionId = associatedQuestion.Id
        });
    }

    ExamAttempt.ExamAttemptAnswers.AddRange(answersToAdd);
    UnitOfWork.ExamAttempt.Update(ExamAttempt);

    var result = await UnitOfWork.Save();

    if (result < attemptDto.answers.Count) 
    {
        return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Failure("Can't update attempt answers");
    }

    return OperationResult<ExamAttemptReponseDto>.Success(null);
}

What I've tried:

Ensured no other processes are modifying the data
Checked that the correct ExamAttempt and related entities are loaded
Verified that no data is being concurrently updated from another user


Can you include the definition for the ExamAttemptAnswer entity? Also, what database are you using? I suspect the issue is that you are trying to assign the ID manually. By default Key columns that EF recognize by convention are expected to act as Identity unless you explicitly mark them as DatabaseGeneratedOption.None When EF gets confused around Keys you end up with the Expected 1, affected 0 error. This can be caused by background changes or misconfiguration.

Try to remove UnitOfWork.ExamAttempt.Update(ExamAttempt);, if entity is tracked, it may cause update problems.
